# Not getting response header in ratchet websocket over https

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, ratchet

## Client URL

`wss://stage.example.com/?token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

## Nginx server block

```
 map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        ''      close;
    }

server {
 
root /var/www/html/Example/public;

index index.php index.html;
 
server_name stage.example.com;
listen 80 ;
 

      error_log /home/ubuntu/error.log;
      access_log /home/ubuntu/access.log;
      client_max_body_size 10M;
      client_body_buffer_size     32k;
      client_header_buffer_size   8k;
      large_client_header_buffers 8 64k;
      fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
      fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
      proxy_buffer_size   128k;
      proxy_buffers   4 256k;
      proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;


location / {

try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location /chat/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;   
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}  

location ~ \.php$ {
include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
}

location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/stage.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/stage.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = stage.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


listen 80 ;
listen [::]:80 ;
 
server_name stage.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

## (attached image).

[getting request header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QLMo.png)

## changes that I made on the server.

## nginx

I have tried many proxy headers in Nginx. Below are the ones. Even then I am not getting a response.

```
#    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
#    proxy_read_timeout 300s;
#    proxy_send_timeout 300s;
#    proxy_redirect off;
#    proxy_intercept_errors on;
#    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
#    proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
#    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
#    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
#    proxy_hide_header X-Powered-By;

 

    # Set WebSocket headers
#    proxy_set_header Sec-WebSocket-Key $http_sec_websocket_key;
#    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "gzip, deflate";
#    proxy_set_header Sec-WebSocket-Extensions "permessage-deflate";
```

## Supervisor

I m running ratchet WebSocket on the server on port 8090 using supervisor.

The port is open as I have checked it.

it will be helpful if someone points out the problem. Thanks in advance.